# Make array_append in trigger with PostGIS intersection

Tags: qgis, postgis, intersection, array, trigger

I've 2 layers : linestring with column id_line and polygone, drawn by user.
I trying to get id_line on linestring who intersects polygon.
I've got it in qgis with :

```
aggregate(
layer:= 'aep_cana',
aggregate:='concatenate',
expression:=id_cana,
concatenator:='; ',
filter:=intersects($geometry, geometry(@parent)))
```

in default value, It's not really an array, more like a list but it's ok for me.

So I try to make the same thing when I create a polygon, automatically, in my database with a trigger (because in QGIS, users can do anything they want).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
FUNCTION asst.transf_id_line() RETURNS TRIGGER LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $function$ 
BEGIN
    UPDATE asst.test_emprise SET
    list = array_append(list, (SELECT c.id_line FROM line."id_line" AS c WHERE st_within(NEW.geom, c.geom))) ;
END;
$function$
;
```

Doesn't work, I write this code just for idea. 
But I try some simple array_append in trigger, but it makes loop...

So I find WITH RECURSIVE like in 
[Postgis: aggregate function for intersection](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/55561/postgis-aggregate-function-for-intersection)
but I can't apply it to me.
It this a good way or not? How can I use array_append in a trigger?

---

After 2 hours, I can make

```
WITH RECURSIVE idsel AS (
SELECT
    te.id AS idi,
    ARRAY_AGG( c.id_line::TEXT) AS aa
FROM
    asst.test_emprise AS te
CROSS JOIN asst."line" AS c
WHERE
    ST_INTERSECTS(c.the_geom,te.geom)
GROUP BY
    te.id )
--SELECT * FROM idsel;
UPDATE asst.test_emprise AS op SET list = idsel.aa FROM idsel WHERE idsel.idi = op.id;
```

But I can't transform in trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things wrong in the original trigger function:
1) the same table as the target table is used in an `update` statement (likely creating the loop you are mentioning)
2) the entire table is updated, not just the `new` record.
3) don't use `array_append` but rather [`array_agg`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html), to avoid repeating all the values in case of a polygon update
4) there is no `return` statement.

Here is a possible solution, assuming it is a [`before`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html) trigger

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE
FUNCTION asst.transf_id_line() RETURNS TRIGGER LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $function$ 
BEGIN
    NEW.list = SELECT array_agg(c.id_line) 
               FROM line."id_line" AS c 
               WHERE st_intersects(NEW.geom, c.geom) ;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$function$
;
```

Comment: Thank, I just wrote instead    NEW.list = (SELECT array_agg(c.id_line) 
               FROM line."id_line" AS c 
               WHERE st_intersects(c.geom, NEW.geom)) ; and it's fine.